# OJDBC : PreparedStatement batchupdate- setQueryTimeout

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am planning to use `PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout` method in case of batch update. In the PreparedStatement doc, I can find the below note:

> Note: In the case of Statement batching, it is implementation defined as to whether the time-out is applied to individual SQL commands added via the addBatch method or to the entire batch of SQL commands invoked by the executeBatch method (consult your driver vendor documentation for details).

Now, how do I find, in case of  batching, how it is implemented for Oracle's JDBC driver? Is the timeout for a single query or for the entire batch?

Comment: try looking at the driver's documentation

Comment: The best way to know is to set a a simple test with a long taking statement (use e.g. a *sleep* function calls) and to observe the behavior. This can be dependent from your *driver version* and/or from the *version of your RDBMS*.

Comment: The timeout is for the batch. The timer starts when the batch is submitted to the server and if there is no response within the querytimeout then an exception will be thrown.